# How to hide/show a menu in EasyAdminBundle programatically

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I read the EasyAdmin documentation and see a lot of customization, but nothing like programatically set the showing menus. I'm thinking for example hide or show the menus depending of the user logged roles.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is no way yet. https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/issues/885